# fatal: remote heroku already exists

Tags: git, heroku

I am running the following commands and get `fatal: remote heroku already exists.` error.

I dont know what is wrong here, it used to work without errors before.

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'Initial commit'
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:myapp.git
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Open .git/config, you will find

```
[remote "heroku"]
url = git@heroku.com:xxx.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

Change xxx to the app name you want to push. Then

```
git push heroku master
```

It works for me. You can have a try.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add a git remote that already exists.  If you run the `git remote -v` command in the same folder as the commands you previously you will see a list of all the remote repositories you local repository knows about.  You should see two entries called heroku (one for push, one for fetch)

```
git remote -v
```

If you used the `heroku create` command in that same folder, that would have added the git remote repository as the alias heroku.  As has been stated, no need to add it again.

```
# create your project
git init
git add .
git commit -m "useful commit message"

# run heroku create only once (unless you want additional environments - test, stageing)
heroku create  

# deploy to heroku
git push heroku master
```

Continue to enhance your code and add / commit it into your local git repository.  When you are ready to deploy again then push to heroku.

```
# work on your code
git add .
git commit -m "useful commit message"
git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only supposed to run "git remote add" once. Perhaps you are looking for "git push" ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to remote add heroku in the same directory that you did that before?  If so, try doing that in a different one, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want:

```
git add .
git commit -m 'Information about what is in this commit'
git push heroku master
```

Note I prefer `git commit` with the `-m` option on the command line as it gives me another chance to review the stuff before committing.

Comment: I did this and it was working before. I receive, `error: src refspec master does not match any, now.

Comment: Please do `git status` and tell us the results

Comment: This can also happen if the directory is empty.  Please do a `ls` on the directory for us.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at your [.git/config](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments) file? You may have already established a remote for Heroku. And faffaffaff is correct in that you only establish this once and that you need to use the `git push` to push anything to a remote repository, not `git remote add`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two questions here. The first is whether or not the remote heroku app exists, and the second is whether or you wish to push to the existing app or create a new one.

If the remote app doesn't exist, you can opening a terminal in your project directory,  type `heroku create myapp` at the prompt to create the remote app, and then proceed as normally, committing and pushing as you go.

If the remote app does exist,  then `heroku git:remote -a myapp` will point your local directory to that remote app. If it exists and you wish create a new remote one, `heroku create mynewapp` will do that for you. If you don't change the name, you'll see the same fatal error message. You can read more about it in the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#creating-a-heroku-remote).